Who is this actor from "Six of a kind"?
I found this old poster, which appears to be a frame from Six of a kind (1934, a.k.a. "Poker Party").  This scene features W.C. Fields as "Honest John" (it can be viewed on Youtube using these keywords).
However I can't figure who is the actor in black. He seems a minor character (I didn't see the whole movie).
I've checked the cast, but am still lost.


It seems from this clip the character is referred to as "Doc".



That being the case, I suspect he is 

"Tammany Young ... Dr. Busby (uncredited)"
IMDB

